# App Submitting error setTouched: method

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to upload my app archive for internal testing with iTunesConnect. At the end of the upload Xcode gives me this error `The app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp: setTouched:` That's weird because i always tried to avoid non-public methods. I searched for the setTouched method in my project but i can't find it anywhere. For my app i'm using these frameworks: parse,google map and Facebook. Maybe it's something related to them? Any suggestion?

EDIT:
I'm still trying to fix this. After locating the app bundle in the generated archive i run the line `strings MyApp | grep 'setTouched'`in the terminal and i get 4 result

```
setTouched:
setTouchedLink:
setTouched:
setTouchedLink:
```

but i am unable to find them. How can i locate exactly what file contains them?

I also tried completely removing the GoogleMap sdks from my project and the Validation succeeded. So the issue it's clearly in the GoogleMap sdk.

Another thing i tried is the downgrade from GoogleMap sdk 1.9.0 (the last) to 1.8.1. Only difference is that the terminal command gives me 2 result (setTouched) instead of 4 but the validation still fails. I wish i could just drop this framework but i can't because I'm using google places api and i need to show those places on a google map (Places API Policies).

Comment: Did you also look for `.touched =`? This is another way you might have called `-setTouched:`.

Comment: Just tried, nothing found..